# Can someone please correct the tag "jojorabbit" to "jojo-rabbit"?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jojorabbit is incorrect, it should be **jojo-rabbit** ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jojo_Rabbit ), but when I enter that one it is rejected as "too close to the existing tag".

Comment: In the future, moderator flags tend to work better for clear-cut cases like that.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Ah, OK. FYI the error said to take it up in Meta. ;-)

Comment: No problem, better safe than sorry.